# why the windowController is dealloc but the subview is not dealloc

Tags: macos, view, dealloc

I add a subview cutView in a windowController.

when the cut action is done, I set cutView be nil and its delegate be nil.
I thought the cutView will be dealloc.

So when I do cutAction again, I init a curView again.

when I close the Window, I find the memory is not decrease.

then I add a log in the dealloc of cutView and window, I found the window's dealloc is called but the cutView is never called.

Then I googled but did not find solution.

Thanks for help ~ ^_^

Comment: Because,there is some object still hold a strong reference to the `cutView `,either a block,a delegate,or something else.Maybe you should post some code

Comment: @Leo thanks, i will check my code first ^_^, if it still can be dealloc , I will post the code for help ˊ_>ˋ

Comment: @Leo thanks very much, I find the problem. In my cutView, I add a local monitor for NSKeyDown, but I didn't remove it when the window dealloc. So after remove the monitor, cutView can dealloc. 赞 really thanks， this help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Leo said, there is strong reference to the view so it can not be dealloc.